# How to find a element using BySelector Text with ignore case in espresso

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator

Hi my app require a browser to select  , so while opening my app it ask for a browser to be selected and for I that I am using

```
   UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
   device.wait(Until.findObjects(By.text("Chrome")),10000);
   device.findObject(By.text("Chrome")).click();
```

and to select next option Just once or Always , it verifies from device to device some device Shows "ALWAYS" text and some device shows "Always"

device.wait(Until.findObjects(By.text("ALWAYS")),4000);
 device.findObject(By.text("ALWAYS")).click();

is there a way to select the using By selector irrespective of the Text upper case or lower case (ignore casing)

Comment: I had the same question for matching notification button text, which is uppercase on some Android SDKs.  Thank you @Rakib

Answer (score 2):

Use [`By.text(Pattern p)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/BySelector.html#text).

```
Pattern patternToMatch = Pattern.compile("always", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
device.wait(Until.findObjects(By.text(patternToMatch)),4000);
```